# Pass java object to scala application

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

I need to pass .java object from local drive to scala application not as plain text but as **file.java** and save it in mongodb

I have:

```
case class A (var name: String,
              var javaCode : ?? Some.java object type ???)

object A {
      def printVal{
         println ("name : " + name);
         println ("java object : " + javaCode);
      }
}
```

Can I save it as `VARBINARY` how is it in sql.
Reason I do not want to save it as `String`, because I do not need extra logic to insert it to file. After select ferom mongodb I vant to have plain .java object and after simply compile it.

Comment: No such thing like a ".java object" - a java source file IS just that: a plain text file

Comment: Can I just save plain java file as .java to mongodb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907509/how-do-i-save-a-file-to-mongodb