# How to upload a file in mongodb ( no gridfs want with BSON )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to store file,images and documents in mongodb but it takes only null, i am able to store the file in a folder but not able to do the same with mongo.

The .ejs file is as below:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="PatientEmrController">
        <h1>Upload a file</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form ng-submit="uploadFile()" class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="title" ng-model="titleText" class="form-control" required>
                <br><br>


<file-field ng-model="uploadThis" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-success':uploadThis}" preview="uploadPreview" name="up" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg">Select file</file-field>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img ng-src="{{uploadPreview}}" ng-if="uploadPreview" class="img-responsive" >   
        </div>
    </div>
</div> </html>
```

corresponding js file is as::

```
sample.controller('PatientEmrController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.uploadFile=function(){

        if(!$scope.uploadThis){
            alert('Please select a file to upload.')
            return;
        }

        var fd = new FormData();

        //you can also send other fields
        //this will be available as req.body.title
        //NOTE: files must be added AFTER other form data
        fd.append('title', $scope.titleText);

        //nacho relates to what we called the file
        //in the api on sails
        fd.append('nacho', $scope.uploadThis);
        $http.post('/api/burrito', fd, {
            //transformRequest: angular.identity,
            //headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            up:$scope.uploadThis,
            title: $scope.titleText,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log('upload data',data);
            if(data.result){

                alert('file uploaded. See .tmp/uploads folder.');
            }


        })
        .error(function(err){
            alert('there was an error uploading the file.');
            console.log(err);
        });        
    }


}]);
```

controller file in api is as follows::

```
 module.exports = {


torta:function(req,res){

    console.log('form body',req.body);


    req.file('nacho').upload(function(err,files){





            Filecontroller2.create({
                up: req.param('up'),
              title: req.param('title')
           })


            .exec(function createCB(err, created){
                     if (err)
                      {
                       return res.negotiate(err);
                      }
                       else
                      {
                        return res.ok();
                      }
              });










        if(err) return res.send(400,{result:false,error:err});


        if(!files) return res.send(400,{result:false,error:'Unable to upload file'});


        console.log('file data',err,files);

        console.log('uploaded file path',files[0].fd)



        res.send({result:true,files:files});


    });
 }  };
```

model in api is::

```
module.exports = {


  schema: true,
  attributes: {




     up: {
    type: 'jpg',
     columnName: 'up' 
    },

    title: {
      type: 'string',
     // required: true
     columnName: 'title' 
    }



  }
};
```

This is my sails controller code with gridfs coding, please take a look.

```
uploadAvatar: function (req, res) {


  console.log('form body',req.body);
  var patientID=req.session.me;

  req.file('avatar').upload(function(err,files){
    // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
    //maxBytes: 10000000

    adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
    //uri: 'mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][/[database[.bucket]]'
     uri:'mongodb://kal:kal@localhost:27017/medoolDB.bucket',
    },function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.negotiate(err);
      return res.ok();
    }

    // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
    if (uploadedFiles.length === 0){
      return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
    }


    filecontroller2.findOne({patientID:patientID}, function foundFilecontroller(err, fcontroller) {
    console.log(req.method);
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!fcontroller){

             filecontroller2.create({
                 up:req.param('up'),
      })

             .exec(function createCB(err, created){
                       if (err)
                          {
                           return res.negotiate(err);
                          }
                           else
                          {
                               return res.ok();
                          }
                  });
            }

            else
            {


    // Save the "fd" and the url where the avatar for a user can be accessed
    filecontroller2.update({ patientID:patientID}, {

      // Generate a unique URL where the avatar can be downloaded.
      avatarUrl: require('util').format('%s/user/avatar/%s', sails.getBaseUrl(), req.session.me),

      // Grab the first file and use it's `fd` (file descriptor)
      avatarFd: uploadedFiles[0].fd
    })
    .exec(function (err){
      if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
      return res.ok();
    });


    if(err) return res.send(400,{result:false,error:err});
    if(!files) return res.send(400,{result:false,error:'Unable to upload file'});
     console.log('file data',err,files);
     console.log('uploaded file path',files[0].fd)



            //send response

            //result:true -- file upload successful
            //files:files -- send uploaded file data to the front end
            res.send({result:true,files:files});


}

}

}
```

Comment: why do you want to store a file in mongodb ? just store it on a disk and save the url in your database, it's easier, faster and better at every level for your database.

Comment: actually i want my data to be stored in mongodb only on server so that i can use it , when so ever required. like images or other documents

Comment: mongodb is perfectly capable of storing binary data as a document. I can't see the problem you're experiencing with saving the document - can you provide the code where you're saving to mongo? Do you get any errors?

Comment: there is no error but null is being passed in my collection in place of the image i am uploading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save a file to MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907509/how-do-i-save-a-file-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to store files into a mongoDB take a look into [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed
>   the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.
>
> Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the
>   file into parts, or chunks [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), and stores each chunk as a separate
>   document. By default, GridFS uses a chunk size of 255 kB; that is,
>   GridFS divides a file into chunks of 255 kB with the exception of the
>   last chunk. The last chunk is only as large as necessary. Similarly,
>   files that are no larger than the chunk size only have a final chunk,
>   using only as much space as needed plus some additional metadata.
>
> GridFS uses two collections to store files. One collection stores the
>   file chunks, and the other stores file metadata. The section GridFS
>   Collections describes each collection in detail.
>
> When you query GridFS for a file, the driver will reassemble the
>   chunks as needed. You can perform range queries on files stored
>   through GridFS. You can also access information from arbitrary
>   sections of files, such as to “skip” to the middle of a video or audio
>   file.
>
> GridFS is useful not only for storing files that exceed 16 MB but also
>   for storing any files for which you want access without having to load
>   the entire file into memory

Comment: NO gridfs,  i want to use BSON

Comment: Hi Dude, Actually, I am capable of using Gridfs mannually storing files or songs etc with command prompt(commands) of mongo, like this:ongofiles.exe -d gridfs put song.mp3 and db.fs.files.find(),db.fs.chunks.find({files_id:ObjectId('534a811bf8b4aa4d33fdf94d')}),  i got the expected result, but i can not understand , how to use gridfs in code(angular or sails code).

Comment: I updated my code above,I posted my sails controller with gridfs coding.please take a look.The error i got is   uri:'mongodb://kal:kal@localhost:27017/medoolDB.bucket',
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :