# simple way to upload image in mongo db using sails js

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I want to upload a image in my sails application. how to define the model and how to store the image into database and how to download it. Can anyone please help.
db: mongo.

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

  employeeId:{
      type: 'string'
    },
 addressproof:{
      type:______________
},
```

what should i declare the type fro address proof. I want the user too upload address proof image. and in controller what should i write so that can store and retrieve the address proof.

Comment: jfgi "mongodb store files"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907667/2308005

Comment: you don't need, any special type. Just use string and store the filename or any identifier. and you can upload file using https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads/uploading-to-grid-fs

Comment: Just upload the image on any file server like AWS S3. And store its path in Database.

Answer (score -1):

[you can use gridFS mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs) for saving your files into mongodb .

and before it u must get your file with :

---

```
req.file('yourFileName').upload({
maxBytes: 10000000 },(err,uploadedFiles)=>{
if(err)
  {
  // res your error
  } 
    const file = uploadedFiles.map(item => fs.createReadStream(item.fd))
 }
);
```

---

and then you can save your const file that mentioned in above code and save it with gridFS.

dont forget that u need to add :`const fs = require('file-system')` to start of your code.

Comment: You have  rejected  the edit  answer and added it as your own things , it is very bad

Comment: @DulajKulathunga witch edit answer.  I didn't edit other answers.