# Save file to mongoDb using socketio-file-upload

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am newbe in mongo and socketio-file-upload(siofu) and cant find how to save file that I get from siofu to mongoDB instead of hdd.
So I Have on server side:

```
        const uploader = new siofu();
        uploader.dir = "./public/uploads";
        uploader.listen(socket);
        uploader.on("saved", function(event) {
            //const fileBody =  event.file['someProperty'] //maybe I should take some prop here
            // should I make transformation fileBody to BSON ?
            const fileMsg = {room: roomId, from: userName}
            message.save(fileMsg, (result) => {
                io.in(roomId).emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, fileMsg);
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use socketio-file-upload to upload files from clients to server and just don't specified the `uploader.dir` so `uploader.on("saved")` never excuted then you can get the file by `uploader.on("complete")` event and by `event.file` you have file to store in mongodb as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907667/14442277).

So your code should change like this

```
const uploader = new siofu();
uploader.listen(socket);
uploader.on("complete", function(event) {
   const file=  event.file;
   //saving to mongodb

});
```